# How to create SQL database connectivity in cocoa

Tags: sql, database, cocoa

I am creating a Preference Pane (for System Preferences). I want to fetch data from an SQL database. How do i do that? Please tell me about the code for basic SQL database connectivity in Cocoa.

Comment: Generally, preferences on a Mac are not stored in a SQL DB but rather in plist files.

Comment: What SQL engine are you using on the back end?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to fetch from a SQL database, there are a number of wrapper libraries you could use.

1. [FMDB](http://code.google.com/p/flycode/) (SQLite only)
2. [FDO](http://github.com/drichardson/fdo)  (SQLite only)
3. [CocoaMySQL](http://code.google.com/p/mysql-cocoa-framework/) (MySQL only)

Depending on your data needs, I might actually leverage a scripting language and call that (somehow) from your PrefPane. For example, create a bundle using PyObjC or MacRuby and use SQLAlchemy or ActiveRecord as appropriate.

Comment: +1 DEFINITELY use a wrapper.  There's no good reason to use the sqlite C API directly.